# Error preverifying class java during build (BlackBerry)

Tags: java, compiler-construction, blackberry, build

I'm trying do build and debug a small project for BlackBerry.

During the build I'm getting this error *Error preverifying class java* ...

I read on the net this error could be caused by referencing multiple projects but I tried to move every package in a single project but the error is still there.

I tried with multiple JDE version (currently 4.7) and the Java compiler is set to 1.6. Eclipse version is 3.4.1 as recommended by RIM's documentations.

Edit for clarification

To clarify: I'm not referencing exterlan JARs, only "my" Classes.

The Error preverifying class is thrown on a very simple class (4 private field with getters/setters, implementing serializable, that's all!). What's weird is that I got the error only on this class. I have others classes like this, but these are ok.

I changed the compliance level to 1.4 but the error persists...

Does someone have some clue?

Comment: Are you trying to build with a third-party JAR file?

Comment: Is the compiler compliance level set to 1.4?  In Eclipse did you create the project as a BlackBerry project or a regular Java project?

Comment: @Jonathan @Marc I'm not referencing external jars and the compliance level is 1.6. Is 1.4 mandatory?

Comment: 1.4 is mandatory for BlackBerry apps.

Comment: if you would selfanswer this question with some detailed explanation, quotes and links that would be great and one more question would be closed on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got what's wrong!

First of all, I was trying to port an Android project to BlackBerry, and since you program both device in Java I thought: ok, just go ahead and implement the device specific classes... But that's not completely true!
So to make it compile I included in the BlackBerry project the JRE System Library, thinking it was just "right". But...

BlackBerry **does not** use Java SE as Android does. They implemented their own libraries.* (as pointed out here [Blackberry JDE ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428891/blackbery-jde-arraylist/1429744#1429744))

So the error "Error preverifying class java" was actually caused by a external JAR, and this JAR was the JRE System library...

To fix this, I removed JRE and replaced all the standard classes (like ArrayLists etc) with RIM's implementation :(